# How can i fix the resolution with texture painting?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, texture-painting

When i try to paint my model with texture painting, the texture (if low resolution or high) looks blurry and pixelated, not even close to the base 'picture', how can i fix this?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Edit: i made new UVs (project by bounds) and added another image (512p) and it works kind of better, but now it seems that **what i want to achieve is that the image/tile size is smaller**, so i can paint those 'rocks' smaller' taking less part of the map.

[image]

Edit 2: I changed the values of 'Size X, Y and Z' on the 'context' options, to 0.1, the 'brush' paints bigger, if i add more numbers it paint smaller, but i need it to be smaller than that.

Edit 3: I added a checker texture and it seems to work fine about the proportions i need, now the problem is that **it looks blurry...**

[image]

Comment: not sure what we looking at, but seems that it is working ok, maybe the base image resolution is not sufficient?

Comment: What are we seeing here - the left, is that the image editor in paint mode? On the right, is that the mesh in solid view? I'm not sure what to say since there are variables possible here with preferences on image resolution handling that might affect it. What does the texture look like when imported to the view as its own image plane?

Comment: I edited my question, i made new UVs and it works better, maybe the resolution is the problem but what i need is that the 'tile size' is smaller, even if i have smaller or bigger pictures.

Comment: I added a checker texture and it works fine about the proportions, but now it looks blurry...does anyone know how to make it work with its full resolution/quality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know If I understand you correctly BUT if you paint on a low image res you will get low res texture quality!
Here is a pattern I made painted on a 4098x4098 vs 256x256 texture:
[image]

My pattern is high res but when you project it on a low res texture you will get exactly that. if you want to get variable texture res on your painting I suggest you to check material painting in blender. You could bake it after that painting it to your desired resolution.

Comment: It seems that's the only fix for now, what i wanted was to somehow 'increase' the resolution without go much higher, because my computer can't handle it....yet, some softwares like Zbrush let increase the resolution when painting without problem, then 'bake it' somehow into the final export, but blender won't let me do that..

Comment: it would be better to use Procedural, or Seamless textures if it is a terrain